# Proper way to use strongly-typed Ids with IdentityUser in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, domain-driven-design

I'm following clean architecture and Domain Driven Design in my project. I'm using strongly typed Id for my User entity. User entity is extended from `ASP.NET` `IdentityUser` class. But my issue is when I use a Strongly typed Id for my `IdentityUser`, I also have to use same type for `IdentityRole` type. `IdentityRole<UserId>`. I'm thinking whether this is correct or not. Because IdentityRole doesn't need to have UserId type right?

When I need to create a User role it looks like this,

```
new IdentityRole<UserId>(UserRoles.User) { Id = new UserId(Guid.NewGuid()) }
new IdentityRole<UserId>(UserRoles.Admin) { Id = new UserId(Guid.NewGuid()) }
```

Is there any other proper way to use Strongly typed Ids with IdentityUser? Or is there anything I'm doing wrong?

**User Entity**

```
public class User : IdentityUser <UserId>
{
    public override UserId Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    
    private User(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string passwordHash)
    {
        // assignments...
    }
    
    public static Result<User> Create(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password)
    {
        // user creation code...
    }
}
```

**UserId**

```
public record UserId (Guid Value);
```

**IdentityDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationUserIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<UserId>,UserId>
{
    public ApplicationUserIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationUserIdentityDbContext> options) 
        : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.HasDefaultSchema("User");

        builder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(u => u.Id)
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value, 
                value => new UserId(value));
 
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole<UserId>>()
            .Property(userRole => userRole.Id)
            .HasConversion(
                userRoleId => userRoleId.Value, 
                value => new UserId(value));
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationUserIdentityDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole<UserId>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationUserIdentityDbContext>();
```

PS:
*I'm using AddIdentityCore instead AddIdentity because I've two IdentityUser types in my system. Because I can't call AddIdentity twice I'm using AddIdentityCore.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a proper solution for my issue.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [NotMapped]
    public new UserId Id 
    { 
       get => new UserId(new Guid(base.Id).ToString());  
       private set => base.Id = value.Value.ToString(); 
    }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    
    private User(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string passwordHash)
    {
        // assignments...
    }
    
    public static Result<User> Create(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string password)
    {
        // user creation code...
    }
}
```

with this approach I can use strongly-typed id with my Entity following clean architecture and Domain Drive Design. using `new` keyword for Id field, I'm hiding my base class Id field to external. Because I'm using `NotMapped` annotation it won't map this strongly-typed Id column to database.